# How to execute key combination (^,, f) in sublime REPL?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text

I installed sublime REPL where the key map for evaluation file content in REPL is "^,,f".

[image]

How can I use keyboard for clicking the key sequence? I tried ',',',', and 'f' while pushing control key, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It was "^," and "f". I mean, first click "^,", and then click "f" to invoke the key stroke.